# Change UIButton size while finger is touching it/while it's being dragged

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, touch-event

I have a draggable UIButton. I'd like for it to have a different background image while it's being dragged or touched. The image I would like to use is twice the size of the normal one. I've tried the normal:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonHighlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

but that doesn't work. Any ideas or tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: I havent had chance to try and implement this to see how good it is/if its fully what youre looking for, but what about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939866/uiview-animation-change-size-of-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTouch:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTouchCancel:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];

            -(void)btnTouch:(id)sender{
                UIButton *button=sender;
                [button setBackgroundImage:buttonHighlightedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }

            -(void)btnTouchCancel:(id)sender{
                UIButton *button=sender;
                [button setBackgroundImage:buttonNormalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
```

Comment: You need to resize the button's frame to fit the new image, but this answer works. Thanks!